# How to add Login menu to the first sidebar (secondary menu)

Tags: blocks, users

I need to remove from the 'secondary menu' the login/logout menu from the header, and display in the first sidebar,

It doesnt seem to be as easy as just draging and dropping in blocks,

Comment: Cleared the cache after moving block? Did you save the blocks' settings?

Comment: Use LoginToboggan to further expand your login functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the secondary menu (admin/structure/menu/settings).

Then, on the blocks admin screen (admin/structure/block), place the User menu in the first sidebar.